# how to disappear input field in java script(not the value)

Tags: javascript, php

i have bootstrap model it have drop down .according to the drop down result i have display different input text field .my problem is if the select some option close the model and then open previous selected item input field is still in here .how do i remove it?

```
  $(document).on('click', '.month_ot_resqust', function(){
    $('#overtime_requset').modal('show');
    clear_field();
  });
```

**clear function**
   this will reset the all the form data.but not remove in input field

```
    function clear_field()
  {
    $('#overtime_requset_form')[0].reset();
    $('#error_from_date').text('');
    $('#error_type').text('');
    $('#total_number_employee').text('');
    $('#total_number_hours').text('');
    $('#hours').val('');//this id input field i want disappear
  }
```

input field

```
<input type="text" name="hours" id="hours"  class="form-control" value="00:00:00" />
```

Comment: java to javascript is same as pain to painting.

Comment: okay that mistake .thank you for correction

Comment: you can make that field as hidden using: $('#hours').val('').hide(); Will this suffice your need OR do you trying to make something else.

Comment: thank it working fine.